How to use joinedload in a subquery with SQLAlchemy?
I have two ORM models defined. with flask sql alchemy. I have a many to many relationship between the two.
artists_artworks_mapping = db.Table(
    'artists_artworks_mapping',  
    db.Column("artwork_id",
            db.String(100),
            db.ForeignKey('artworks.artwork_id'),
            primary_key=True
    ),
    db.Column("artist_id",
            db.String(100),
            db.ForeignKey('artists.artist_id'),
            primary_key=True
    )
)
class Artists(db.Model):
    artist_id = db.Column(
            db.String(100),
            primary_key=True,
            )
    artist_name = db.Column(
            db.String(100),
            )
    artworks_rel = db.relationship(
            "Artworks",
            secondary = artists_artworks_mapping,
            viewonly = True,
            back_populates = "artists_rel"
            )

class Artworks(db.Model):
    artwork_id = db.Column(
            db.String(100),
            primary_key=True,
            )
    artwork_name = db.Column(
            db.String(100),
            )
    artists_rel = db.relationship(
            "Artists",
            secondary = artists_artworks_mapping,
            viewonly = True,
            back_populates = "artworks_rel"
            )

I am trying to query my data like this:
columns = ['artist_id', 'artist_name']
join_columns = ['artwork_id']
subq = db.session.query(Artists).options(load_only(*columns))
subq = subq.options(joinedload(getattr(Artists, 'artworks_rel')).load_only(*join_columns))
subq = subq.filter(Artists.artist_id=="my_id")
subq = subq.subquery()
query = db.session.query(Artists.artist_id, func.string_agg(subq.c.artwork_id, ',')).select_from(subq).groupby(Artists.artist_id)

My issue is that the .subquery() modifies my subquery statement and therefore my final query doesn't find the right columns when I try a select_from.
I am using SQLAlchemy==2.0.19
From what I understood, joinedload and subquery dont work well together. The subquery is modified from
SELECT artists.artist_id AS artists_artist_id, artworks_1.artwork_id AS artworks_1_artwork_id, artworks_1.artwork_name AS artworks_1_artwork_name
FROM artists LEFT OUTER JOIN (artists_artworks_mapping AS artists_artworks_mapping_1 INNER JOIN artworks AS artworks_1 ON artworks_1.artwork_id = artists_artworks_mapping_1.artwork_id) ON artists.artist_id = artists_artworks_mapping_1.artist_id
WHERE artists.artist_id = %(artist_id_1)s

to
SELECT {all the columns from artists} FROM artists WHERE artists.artist_id = %(artist_id_1)s) AS anon_1

I tried to use from_statement but it adds a cross join whenever I try to query a column from it.

Any updates on this one?
